# System.XML.Linq assembly: The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-xml

I have some strange error in my project:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

BUT I did add a reference to "System.Xml.Linq" assembly. Also I have it in "using" section.

Code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

//...........

APIConnection VK;

public override Collection MakeCollection(
        CollectionRequestContext context)
    {

//............
        Dictionary<string, string> q = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach (string item in context.Query.AllKeys)
        {
            q.Add(item,context.Query.Get(item));
        }

        ///Here I have 3 errors
        VK= new APIConnection("", q, ErrorHandler, true);


        //Error 1: The type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' 
        //is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
        //You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.Linq...
        // 
        //Error 2: The best overloaded method match for 
        //'APIConnection.APIConnection(string, 
        // System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>,
        // ApiCallBackHandler<System.Xml.Linq.XDocument>, bool)' 
        //has some invalid arguments
        //
        //Error 3: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to 
        //'ApiCallBackHandler<System.Xml.Linq.XDocument>'   

//............
    }


    void ErrorHandler(XDocument result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something wrong...");
        }
    }
```

Just in case: 
1. I have similar project with exactly the same part of code and it's work!
2. Project with error is WebProject and project that's work is a Silverlight Class Library

Why I have this error?

## UPD

APIConnection constructor:

```
public APIConnection(string secret, Dictionary<string,string> query, ApiCallBackHandler<XDocument> errorCalback, bool testmode=false)
    {
        startInfo = new StartInfo();

        if (query != null)
        {
            string tmp;
            bool isRequiredSet = true;
            isRequiredSet = query.TryGetValue("api_url", out startInfo.api_url) || isRequiredSet;
            isRequiredSet = query.TryGetValue("api_id", out startInfo.api_id) || isRequiredSet;
            isRequiredSet = query.TryGetValue("api_settings", out startInfo.api_settings) || isRequiredSet;
            if (!isRequiredSet)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Missing required values.");

        }

        startInfo.server_secret = secret;

        dataProvider = new DataProvider(startInfo,errorCalback);
    }
```

And DataProviders constructor is:

```
    public DataProvider(StartInfo info, Delegate globalErrorCallback=null)
    {
        startInfo = info;
        _globalErrorCallback = globalErrorCallback;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the constructor for the APIConnection class?

Comment: Yes, sure. Just a minute

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the errors in a Silverlight project, in a web project and in a web site - all of them without being able to provoke the error. Are you sure that you have System.Xml.Linq included in all related projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code in a separate Silverlight library that the application assembly is referencing?  If so, make sure your application assembly (the main Silverlight project) also has a reference to System.Xml.Linq assembly; assembly references do not automatically cascade.

**Update:**

I think I missed the crux of the problem before.  It sounds like you're wanting to reference a Silverlight assembly (class library) in a non-Silverlight assembly (web project).  This is supported, but only for a subset of the core Silverlight assemblies.  System.Xml.Linq is not one of those core libraries that .NET can reference.

When I encountered the assembly referencing limitations between Silverlight and .NET before, I opted to use *code sharing* through linked files rather than assembly referencing.  This is where you compile the same code into two different assemblies.  [Here's an article](http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/10/11/sharing-code-between-.net-and-silverlight-platforms.aspx) someone wrote explaining the technique.

Comment: APIConnection - in Library and I use it in project. I have reference in both project and library

Comment: Is the version of System.Xml.Linq being referenced the same for the two assemblies and the right Silverlight version?

Comment: NO! :( Version of System.Xml.Linq in Library is 2.0.5.0 and in WebProject the version is 4.0.0.0! How can I refrense System.Xml.Linq 2.0.5.0 to WebProject??